# React js manifest.json not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I worked on a React project and suddenly my OS crashed. I reinstall the OS and get a clone of the project and try to run it. The previously run application is now broken.

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'


URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/fonts/index.css'
```

My package version

```
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",

"start": "react-app-rewired start",
```

And I have this file called **config-overrides.js**

```
const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        webpack: function (config, env) {
            config.resolve.alias['pdfjs-dist'] = path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf');
            return config;
        },
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="public/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon/favicon-16x16.png"> -->

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Using Google Font -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Public+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Using Local Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fonts/index.css" />

  <title>Application</title>
  <!-- <meta name="description"
    content="The starting point for your next project with Minimal UI Kit, built on the newest version of Material-UI ©, ready to be customized to your style" /> -->
  <meta name="keywords" content="react,material,kit,application,dashboard,admin,template" />
  <meta name="author" content="Minimal UI Kit" />
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think the problem is this.

[image]

Request URL is like this

```
http://localhost:8080/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try solve this using `create-react-app` `build` which creates a build folder. Also  `%PUBLIC_URL%` string is replaced behind the scenes. So we cant directly serve that folder. Instead we have to generate using `build`

Use `yarn build` or `npm run build`. That will generate a build folder containing asset, manifest, and other files.

After that, use that build folder to statically serve your files for production use.